# Google Analytics integration with tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, tags, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I am trying to link Google Analytics account to tag manager account. I needs the UA-tacking id and all they give me is a G- ID and it doesn't reciprocate. I am not seeing any real-time data in google analytics.

Comment: I will try and create new prope

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a Universal Analytics Property to use the relative identifier UA-XXXXXXX-X, follow the instructions of the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you thank you it worked im so happy thank you